# Quadratic objective function in Gurobi

Tags: python, model, gurobi, objective-function

I am building a model with a quadratic objective function. But I am having trouble on how to code it.

v is a matrix of coefficients.

This is the original objective:

```
 x = m.addMVar(shape=n, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")  # binary var
 m.setObjective(v @ x, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

And I need to transform it in : max [(v*x)^2]
I tried this, but it gives an error:

```
 x = m.addMVar(shape=n, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")  # binary var
 m.setObjective(x @ v @ x, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

Could someone help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x @ v @ x requires v to be a matrix (2-dimensional numpy.ndarray); my guess is that v is a vector (1-dimensional numpy.ndarray). If you really mean the expression x1^2 * v1 + ... + xn^2 * vn, then you can write:

```
m.setObjective(x @ np.diag(v) @ x, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```